# 3 Variables are not properly passed in php

Tags: php

I have a question that I need to pass variables to another page with submit. so on one page

```
 echo "<form action='processExceededQty.php' method='post'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='dataProject' id='dataProject' value='$row[PROJECT_NAME]'";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='dataHeadmark' id='dataHeadmark' value='$row[HEAD_MARK]'";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='dataIdentification' id='dataIdentification' value='$row[ID]'";
```

and on the other page processExceededQty.php

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $_POST['dataProject'];
    echo $_POST['dataHeadmark'];
    echo $_POST['dataIdentification'];
}
```

this is the error message I am getting,

> POWERHOUSE
>       Notice: Undefined index: dataHeadmark in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\Content\Fabrication\Update\Fabrication\processExceed
>       edQty.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined index: dataIdentification in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\Content\Fabrication\Update\Fabrication\processExceed
>       edQty.php on line 29

The problem here only the dataProject that is passed to another page.
Please help me with this situation

Comment: What is line 28 and 29?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` - post your results

Comment: Where are your `<input` closing tags?

Comment: why is your input not closed properly?

Comment: I can get it to work... stupid me.. thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML is malformed: each `<input` needs a corresponding `>`:

```
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='dataProject' id='dataProject' value='$row[PROJECT_NAME]'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='dataHeadmark' id='dataHeadmark' value='$row[HEAD_MARK]'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='dataIdentification' id='dataIdentification' value='$row[ID]'>";
```

Comment: +1 Though this is what happens when you try and build great swathes of static HTML with tiny dynamic pieces of PHP; things get missed.

Comment: @Phil especially when done like this. rather do something like `<input type="hidden" name="dataProject" id="dataProject" value="<?=$row[PROJECT_NAME]?>" />` for clarity. Just my opinion.

Comment: Your observation is completely correct. But i think, syntactically its better to have  `/>` instead of just `>` to close input elements.

Comment: @BhavikShah That depends entirely on the `DOCTYPE` in use. For XHTML, sure but for any HTML doctype, `>` is just fine

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing tags for hidden fields.

```
echo "<form action='processExceededQty.php' method='post'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='dataProject' id='dataProject' value='$row[PROJECT_NAME]'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='dataHeadmark' id='dataHeadmark' value='$row[HEAD_MARK]'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='dataIdentification' id='dataIdentification' value='$row[ID]'>"
```

This will work.